# How to allow a string that is a key of a class

Tags: typescript, implicit-typing

I have the following function:

```
export const sortAlphabetically = <T>(array: T[], property: string) => 
    array.sort((a: T, b: T) => 
    a[property].localeCompare(b[property]));
```

The `property` should be a key in T (as string?), no other values should be accepted. I tried with `property: [key in t]` but this doesn't work.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyof` operator should do the trick

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)

```js
export const sortAlphabetically = <
  T extends Record<string, string>
>(array: T[], property: keyof T) =>
  array.sort((a: T, b: T) => a[property].localeCompare(b[property]));
```

You need to assure TypeScript that value of property is `string`. That's why I have used `T extends Record<string, string>`

Comment: Tried this also in the meantime - throws this error: `Property 'localeCompare' does not exist on type 'T[keyof T]'`. Do I have to explicitely have to put it into a string?